# Finding the socks proxy port to set within System.setProperty("socksProxyPort") - windows java -

Tags: java, windows, proxy, socks

i am trying to make an FTP connection  via HTTP using a proxy.
i set the HTTP and HTTPS proxy host and port with the following code :

```
    system.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
    List<Proxy> l = null;
            try {
                l = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://foo/bar"));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (l != null) {

                for (Iterator iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                    java.net.Proxy proxy = (java.net.Proxy) iter.next()

                    InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();

                if (addr != null) {
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));
                    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
                    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));    
                    System.setProperty("socksProxyHost",addr.getHostName());                            
                    System.setProperty("socksProxyPort","xxxx"  );
```

i would like to know if is there a way to know wich one is the configured internet port (in the windows internet proxy control panel) about  the proxy to can set it at Runtime with the code :

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort")
```

i need to do it without the user knows the port and choose it in the software before the connection becouse i would like to do it "automatically" as i can set the HTTP proxy getting the parameters from the system.

I need this becouse i have a strange issue :
If i dont set port number at runtime of the socks proxy my client could not make a PUT or GET request correctly using AXIS2 libraries and a webservice server IF in the windows internet options panel the proxy server is configured with the option : "use the same proxy server for all protocols"

if i unflag that option and i set manually the socks addres (192.168.x.y  port 1080  ) , strangely, the connection goes on without the need to set by code the port with use the same proxy server for all protocols.

I can also try to change the socks port using another one , es 808. I am able to connect with the server if in my code i set the same port with     System.setProperty("socksProxyPort","808")

Answer (score 0):

The library [proxy-vole](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/) contains code to automatically detect the system's proxy settings via various strategies.

As for why your code works when you set a port, I don't know. It feels weird to mix HTTP, FTP and SOAP. You may want to install a local proxy server which allows you to monitor all data which passes through it and set your real proxy as its upstream. That way, you can see how your application tries to talk to the proxy. That will give you clues why it breaks.

Comment: i'm trying to use proxy-vole but i am in the same situation. I need to know the exact socks port and set it becouse both standard proxy selector and p-v doenst solve the problem. I've readed lot of post on internet about issues with socks use (also when you dont need it) , this is why i just want  olny to autodetect socks port  and set it 
i was reading proxyvole documentation but is not easier to find a method to can extract it

Comment: I think the idea of proxy-vole is that you just let it do the setup for you instead of trying to force certain values into System properties. My feeling is that the proxy settings of your OS are wrong; maybe you can't use "use same proxy for everything".